# How to make a themeable web application using CSS?

Tags: css, themes, less

I have an idea for a web application that would allow users to create their own profile pages, and apply custom or pre-defined themes to change the look/feel of their profile page. It would be similar to Wordpress themes, or any other product that utilizes a similar idea. My idea was to build the css using [less](http://lesscss.org/). The users would be able to create/edit their own themes through a GUI interface (pick colors, fonts, etc). When saving a theme, it would update the variables in the .less files, and rebuild the css accordingly.

Is this a feasible or even possible way to apply style themes to a page? Are there any existing solutions out there that already accomplish this?

Comment: Also found that using tools like [DotLess](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) will allow you to deliver CSS generated from LESS files [on the fly](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030310-1.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [jQueryUI themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) it's one way to let users change the style of their profile while limiting the styles to colors and layout mostly. There are jQuery plugins that let them select a theme from a drop down.

A more custom method would be to possibly set inline styles throughout your template wrap them with php and work that into your GUI. So users select a color of a navigation bar and the hex or rgb color is stored into a db table.

Comment: good input, i hadn't thought about using themeroller - storing the user selections in a db table and rendering pages accordingly is along the lines of what i had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

One problem i see here is that the user can change other parts of the page which shouldn't be changeable. For examlpe menus, login buttons etc. This could be a security problem.
So you must limit the users ways how to change the styles. For example only allow to change certain classes with certain params.

Comment: Right, i planned to use a separate css file for each user page, and use a GUI to limit what variables they can change.